# Highcharter and organization chart customisation

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, highcharts

I am tring to make a WBS chart using highcharter R package.

I wish to be able to plot the differents tasks per actions in a straight way under the box whom they come from, rather than in wages. I struggle to find the appropriate option to control this. (even after checking this here https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.organization)

See the code below and what does it returns. Which is almost what I expected, but not exactly. I found the way to control the column position, but this is not working for rows. Moreover the task order is mixed in a weird way for the tasks in column 8 which is not expected of course.

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization', inverted = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = 'WBS') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = 'WBS',
    data = list(
        #Liste action
        list(from = 'T', to = 'A1'),
        list(from = 'T', to = 'A2'),
        list(from = 'T', to = 'A3'),
        list(from = 'T', to = 'A4'),
            
            #A1
            list(from = 'A1', to = 'b1'),
            list(from = 'b1', to = 'P'),
            list(from = 'P', to = 'F1'),
            list(from = 'F1', to = 'AqDo'),
            list(from = 'AqDo', to = 'Ay1'),
            list(from = 'Ay1', to = 'R1'),
            list(from = 'R1', to = 'Ar1'),
            
            #A2
            list(from = 'A2', to = 'b2'),
            list(from = 'b2', to = 'Cx'),
            list(from = 'Cx', to = 'F2'),
            list(from = 'F2', to = 'Pr'),
            list(from = 'Pr', to = 'Ay2'),
            list(from = 'Ay2', to = 'R2'),
            list(from = 'R2', to = 'Ar2'),
            
            #A3
            list(from = 'A3', to = 'b3'),
            list(from = 'b3', to = 'Cx'),
            list(from = 'Cx', to = 'F3'),
            list(from = 'F3', to = 'Pr'),
            list(from = 'Pr', to = 'Ay4'),
            list(from = 'Ay4', to = 'R3'),
            list(from = 'R3', to = 'Ar3'),
            
            #A4
            list(from = 'A4', to = 'Ar4')
    ),
    nodes = list(
        #task list
        list(id = 'T', name = "name", title = "title", color = '#081358', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 0),
        list(id = 'A1', title = 'action1', color = '#2D2F51', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 1),
        list(id = 'A2', title = 'action2', color = '#2D2F51', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 1),
        list(id = 'A3', title = 'action3', color = '#2D2F51', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 1),      
        list(id = 'A4', title = 'action4', color = '#2D2F51', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 1),
            
            #A1
            list(id = 'b1', title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 2),
            list(id = 'P',  title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 3),
            list(id = 'F1', title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 4),
            list(id = 'AqDo', title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 5),
            list(id = 'Ay1', title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 6),
            list(id = 'R1', title = 'A1', color = '#9EC3E7', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 7),
            list(id = 'Ar1', title = 'A1', color = '#B94331', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 8),
            
            #A2
            list(id = 'b2', title = 'A2', color = '#2491A9', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 2),
            list(id = 'Cx', title = 'A2 + A3', color = '#2BA8C4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 3),
            list(id = 'F2', title = 'A2', color = '#2491A9', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 4),
            list(id = 'Pr', title = 'A2 + A3', color = '#2BA8C4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 5),
            list(id = 'Ay2', title = 'A2', color = '#2491A9', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 6),
            list(id = 'R2', title = 'A2', color = '#2491A9', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 7),
            list(id = 'Ar2', title = 'A2', color = '#B94331', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 8),
           
            #A3
            list(id = 'b3', title = 'A3', color = '#34D1F4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 2),
            list(id = 'F3', title = 'A3', color = '#34D1F4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 4),
            list(id = 'Ay4', title = 'A3', color = '#34D1F4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 6),
            list(id = 'R3', title = 'A3', color = '#34D1F4', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), column = 7),
            list(id = 'Ar3', title = 'A3', color = '#B94331', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 8),
            
            #A4
            list(id = 'Ar4', title = 'A4', color = '#B94331', dataLabels = list(color = 'white'), column = 8)
    )
  )
```

and see the plot below

[image]

Maybe the answer could be found by modifying the css, or html, or javaScript source code ? but this would not be logical as an R package has been created to use highchart from Rstudio.

Comment: Could you explain: _I wish to be able to plot the differents tasks per actions in a straight way under the box whom they come from, rather than in wages._ ?

Comment: Do you want to show the data label under the point (box area)?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Not necessarily (about data label)

Comment: there is action 1, 2, 3, 4 listed (second row, darkblue boxes), then per actions several tasks that must to be performed. I would like to see every tasks per action, directly under the box. Considering Action one, I would like that all the boxes with title A1 aligned vertically. And of course this for every actions.

Comment: Have you try manipulate with `offset: '-100%'` inside node? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/698fzvrp/)

Comment: @SebastianHajdus yes, I tried different values of offset. However, I notice something interesting in your example, all the box (product, web, sale) are linked to cto, and not one after one as I did. Maybe that could work.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus I did not found any solution to solve this problem properly so far. I will probably refer this at the company directly.